# django 1.5 only show 500 in production mode

Tags: python, django

After migrate the django from 1.3 to 1.5, in debug mode it work correctly but after switch to prod mode it always show 500 error, it really crazy me, as I can not get any stackoverlfow of the error.

Comment: what does your error log say ?

Comment: Perhaps you need to add [`ALLOWED_HOSTS`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#allowed-hosts) to your `settings.py`?  It's new in django 1.3.6, 1.4.4 and 1.5 and gets me every time.

Comment: yes from the latest document: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/settings/#std:setting-ALLOWED_HOSTS.

Comment: turn on debug=True in your settings.py and see error details